# Linq query to get data from Database using group by clause

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing MVC4 application. I ended up with one complex scenario. I have following table in sql.

```
upld_Id     Label         Value          Commited
1000        DocNumber     123            0
1000        ExpiryDate    01/01/2016     0
1000        Docnumber     456            1
1000        ExpiryDate    01/01/2018     1
```

I am supposed to get output in the below format.

```
upld_Id     Label         OldValue      NewValue 
1000        Docnumber     123           456
1000        ExpiryDate    01/01/2016    01/01/2018
```

I tried as below.

```
var logDetails = (from c in db.logTable
                  join tbl in db.MetaTable on c.id equals tbl.id
                  //GroupBy
                  where  (c.commited==false || c.commited==true) 
                  select new ClassName
                  {
                      //Get Values
                  }).toList();
```

This is what i tried in LINQ. I am not sure how to apply LINQ here

```
var logDetails = (from c in db.ts_upldlog_content
                                      join tbl in db.ts_upld_doc on c.upld_docid equals tbl.upld_docid
                                      join doc in db.tm_doc_type on tbl.upld_doctypeid equals doc.doc_typeid
                                      where c.upld_docid==data
                                 group c by c.upld_contentlabel into grouping
                                 select new logdetails
                                 {
                                    updatedOn=c.updatedOn //Here Error
                                    contentLabel=grouping.Key,
                                    oldValue = grouping.FirstOrDefault(x => x.commited ==false).upld_contentvalue,
                                    newValue = grouping.FirstOrDefault(x => x.commited == true).upld_contentvalue,
                                 }).ToList();
```

Can someone tell me is this possible in LINQ? Thanks

Comment: You must provide what you have tried.. We can help you from there

Comment: Thank you for your message. Actually i tried to write sql query because I am not that much good in Linq. I tried as above. But I am not getting expected output.

Comment: If you want a linq answer then please provide what linq query you have tried. I can help you correct it but not write it for you...

Comment: Thank you. What i tried i posted above. I am not sure about LINQ group by how to apply and on which column to apply. Thank you

Comment: What is the rule by which you decide if it is an "oldValue" or a "newValue"?

Comment: When commited 0 then It is old value. When commited is 1 it is new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group your results by the `Label` and then for each of the `oldValue` and `newValue` retrieve an item that matches the predicate (`commited == 1` / `commited == 0`):

```
var logDetails = (from c in db.ts_upldlog_content
                  join tbl in db.ts_upld_doc on c.upld_docid equals tbl.upld_docid
                  join doc in db.tm_doc_type on tbl.upld_doctypeid equals doc.doc_typeid
                  where c.upld_docid == data
                  group c by new { c.upld_contentlabel, c.updateOn } into grouping
                  select new logdetails
                  {
                      updatedOn = c.Key.updateOn,
                      contentLabel = grouping.Key.upld_contentlabel,
                      oldValue = grouping.FirstOrDefault(x => x.commited ==false).upld_contentvalue,
                      newValue = grouping.FirstOrDefault(x => x.commited == true).upld_contentvalue,
                  }).ToList();
```

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole - Let me know how it goes

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to implement here.  My Commited  is boolean. so I am getting error in ?.Value.

Comment: Hi Gilad. Table name does not contain definition for Value and No extension method value exceptiong first argument of type data could be found. I am getting this error.

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole - the `Value` there is because in your question that is how the column is named. You need to change it to the correct column name

Comment: It is working fine. Thanks a lot. But When i do select new someclassname{ classpropertyname=item .Somevalue} It says item is not defind in the current context

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole - I'll have to see the code as it is now to properly understand and answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125919/discussion-between-niranjan-godbole-and-gilad-green).

Comment: I have posted my code above. how can i fetch other fields from other tables?

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole - See explanation in chat

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sub query for expected result:

```
var logDetails = (from i in db.Tbl
                  where 
                    i.Commited == false
                  select new ClassName
                  {
                    i.Id,
                    i.Label,
                    OldValue = i.Value,
                    NewValue = (db.Tbl.Where(t => t.Id == i.Id && t.Comitted == true).Select(t => t.Value).FirstOrDefault())
                  }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

I would GroupBy (upld_Id, Label) in a new anonymous type...

```
var query = db.logTable.GroupBy(l => new { l.upld_Id, l.Label })
                       .Select(g => new
                       {
                           upld_Id = g.Key.upld_Id,
                           Label = g.Key.Label,
                           OldValue = g.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Commited == 0).Value, 
                           NewValue = g.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Commited == 1).Value,
                       })
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.